# Show that if $f$ is measurable then $\{x\in A:c=f(x)\}$ is measurable for each $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be a bounded measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that if $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable then $\{x\in A:c=f(x)\}$ is measurable for each $c$.

Choose real $c$. Since $f$ is measurable we know that each set $S_n=\{x\in A : c-\frac{1}{n} \le f(x)\le c + \frac{1}{n}\}$ is measurable. Since

$$\{x\in A:c=f(x)\}=\bigcap_n S_n$$

is a countable intersection of measurable sets, it is measurable itself.

Is this correct? I'm asking because up until now I have not had much experience with measure theory.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Looks good to me. However I'm wondering about the hypothesis that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: @M.U. I believe it's a feature of my book, ie. author considers only measures on a bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What definition of measurable function are you using?

Comment: @YungBo $f$ is measurable if and only if $\{x\in X : f(x)<c \}$ is measurable for any $c$.